# Laravel Querybuilder how to skip and take rows from newest to oldest?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, query-builder

Is there a way to skip and take rows from newest to oldest using Laravel Querybuilder?

This is what I currently have:

```
DB::table('decks')->skip(10)->take(5)->get();
```

It skips from the oldest to the newest. Is there a way to make skip start from the newest rows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `orderBy`. Assuming you have a `created_at` field in you table:

```
DB::table('decks')->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->skip(10)->take(5)->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

`DB::table('decks')->latest()->skip(10)->take(5)->get();`

if you want to order another column then pass the column name to the latest method.